# Firebase dynamic Link is not clickable in default messaging app of MI, realme devices

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, sms, firebase-dynamic-links

I am sending invite message using SMS intent but link in invite message is not clickable.
Link is working and clickable in samsung phone (API 24), in oneplus (API 29) but it not clickable in MI , realme devices . And in same  MI phone same messaging app bitly short link is clickable . I have created dynamic link using firebase dynamic link feature , here is my code to send sms using both links i.e firebase dynamic and Bitly short link :

```
String shareMessageFirebase = "Hi testing firebase dynamic link. Sent from Sky.\n https://test200.page.link/2020";

String shareMessageBitly = "Hi testing bitly short link. https://bitly/3n1Xo3k";

             try {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
                    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", shareMessageFirebase);
                    startActivity(sendIntent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Util.showLog(TAG, "Exception  " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

[image: Screenshot of one plus]

[image: Screenshot of samsung device]

[image: Screenshot of Mi Device]

Comment: Its a valid link if that app does not detect it that means its the issue in their app.

Comment: @ADM but in same phone all other links are working

Comment: @HimanshiThakur, have you find any solution for this ?, I am facing same issue, dynamic links  are clickable except MI and realme. and bitly is working well for all devices

Comment: @user3782114 No, still facing this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue any solution you found? @HimanshiThakur